# Solr error : Undefined method Closed? for nil class, in port 8981

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr

I have a rails application for which I have set up the QA Environment and 
I am trying to run solr in QA environment, but whenever i try to start solr it says

```
** Invoke solr:start (first_time) ** Execute solr:start rake aborted!
undefined   method   `closed?' for nil:NilClass, for port 8981
```

The same code works fine on Production.

Whereas solr is running fine for production environment.but its not running for QA environment.

```
development:
  url: http://localhost:8982/solr

production:
  url: http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr

test:
  url: http://127.0.0.1:8981/solr
```

Can anyone help

Comment: It would be helpful to know the version of SOLR you're using. Please also provide the configuration file(s) for the SOLR instance serving on port 8981.

Comment: I am using act_as_solr plugin and the version is v0.9

Comment: The application itself is built on top of rails 2.3.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To overcome this problem what I did was :

created a copy of file **solr** as **solr_qa** under **/etc/init.d** and configured its paths to the qa application's **.. /vendor/plugins/acts_as_solr/solr**.

Then started the solr with the new file:

```
/etc/init.d/solr_qa start
```

also restarted conf file

```
/etc/init.d/httpd restart
```

And my job was done.